# How to use decision trees for survival analysis?

Tags: python, survival-analysis, scikit-survival

I have a problem understanding und applying Decision Trees for Survival Analysis in Python. I have a dataset, with the variables age, weight, size of tumor, volume, ... (all floats) and I want to know if there is a correlation with the overall survival(also a float).

But how can I apply Decision Trees for that? In the literature, I only saw examples where y_train must be a categorical variable (such as 0 or 1, benign or malignant, ...) but it does not work on continuous variables like floats.

However I want to create a decision tree, so that in the end you can find out that with a tumor size of > xx and a volume of >yy your predictes overall survival is about < zzz.

Can someone help me out with my problem? Does anyone has an idea where to read more about this topic?

Comment: could you give more insight about three or more survival scenario ?, I mean for the target variable Y.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Scikit-survival package provides some ensemble decision tree models like [RandomSurvivalForest](https://scikit-survival.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/generated/sksurv.ensemble.RandomSurvivalForest.html) and also classical models like the Cox model [CoxPhSurvivalAnalysis](https://scikit-survival.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/generated/sksurv.linear_model.CoxPHSurvivalAnalysis.html).

The docs provide a good code [example](https://scikit-survival.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/random-survival-forest.html). Regarding the target variable `y`, at least in this case the documentation states

> y – A structured array containing the binary event indicator as first field, and time of event or time of censoring as second field.